# after installed ubuntu 16.04, win8.1 start logo is changed

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

After installing Ubuntu 16.04, Win8.1 start logo is changed.
Is Ubuntu attacking Windows (Win 8.1) when dual booting?

[image: click here to shows it..]

Comment: Attacking? :D Yes, Ubuntu did attack Windows installation in a way when it replaced Windows bootloader with Grub (that is completely correct and harmless for a dual-boot system). However, this looks like Windows don’t set graphics correctly after Grub.

Comment: and i have new question. how to upgrade win8.1 to win10?

Comment: you cant even upgrade to 10 for free any more

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @EshanMalimbada _“how to upgrade win8.1 to win10?”_ This is a wrong place to ask such questions, try [Super User](https://superuser.com/).